# pre_delete signal error

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I want to delete all **Generic Foreign Key relationships** belonging to a **Contact** when said contact is deleted.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Contact):

    def contact_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        from unsubscribe.models import Unsubscribe
        unsubscribe_list = Unsubscribe.objects.filter(object_id=instance)

        for item in unsubscribe_list:
            item.delete()
```

My issues are, how do I get the object_id of the instance. I only want to delete the related items of the object I'm deleting?

Comment: Did you try `instance.pk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instance` is the `Contact` object here. So, `instance.id` would give you the id of the contact object

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Contact, dispatch_uid='<whatever>')
def contact_delete(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    from unsubscribe.models import Unsubscribe
    unsubscribe_list = Unsubscribe.objects.filter(object_id=instance.id, content_type__model='contact')

    for item in unsubscribe_list: #This should be a single element in the queryset. 
        item.delete()
```